# Check if file was created and deleted?

Tags: linux, bash, file, testing, signals

I need to test a program that creates temporary file. When run finishes it deletes the file. How can I check it file has be created and deleted.

I am thinking about sending some signals to process (like Ctrl-Z) to suspend it and check but should be simpler ways.

I am using bash in Linux.

Comment: Presumably, the file is created in order to produce some other condition you can check for. I would check for that (which would confirm the temp file was used and therefore created) and that the temporary file no longer exists (which would imply it was either deleted or never created, but we're ruling out the "never created" condition in the first check).

Comment: For testing, you can change the delete part with a move to /tmp for e.g. If at the end of execution you find your file in /tmp, it means everything goes as expected. This way you can additionally check the file content if you need to.

Comment: @redobot how to change delete part to move /tmp ?

Comment: in bash mv filename /tmp .. if you are using other Language check how to do it .. for example in C or C++ you can use rename (srcpath, destpath)

Comment: The file is created and deleted by program and I can't change it.

Comment: "The file is created and deleted by program and I can't change it." then you can't properly test that aspect. Go to the developers and ask them for some hook or tell them you can't test that aspect. I know this idea is unpopular, but there should be a dialog between dev and QA; dev shouldn't toss things over "the wall" and expect QA to wave a magic wand over it. (I've managed a Dev&QA team and got the Devs to alter their *prima donna* attitude toward QA.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have access to the program code, then you could use the **strace** tool to intercept all the system calls issued by the process. Then with simple greps you can look for file creation, deletion and all related operations. Probably you have to use the "-f" option to make sure everything is logged including the operations performed by any process's child

Comment: Seems it is what I need. Will try it. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect, does it finally worked for you? .. if yes, then plz accept the answer so more people can find the solution if they run in a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

If you can, with some certainty, know when the file will be created you can use [the link command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln) to hang onto the file. For example, in the code you are testing there is a sequence like:

```
open some temporary file for writing
# do stuff
write stuff to open file
close file
unlink file
```

If, in between the open and unlink in the tested program, you can run

```
ln the_temp_file my_temp_file
```

then when the unlink occurs, the tested program will have no idea that you have a hard link to the file so it didn't get removed from the file system.

This will not work for symbolic links `ln -s` so your link will need to be on the same physical device.